# How to test Foreign Keys in Flask with unittest

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, python-unittest

How are you?

I need to test adding information to a database but I don't know how to test the integration of the foreign key with unit tests.
the information without me adding Nullable as false was being added without problems
I am using Flask 1.1.2 and Flask-sqlaclhemy 2.4.4
the database is mysql.
follow the code of model:

```
from app import db

class Client(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clients'
    code = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name_fantasy = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    contact = db.relationship('ContactClient', backref='client', lazy='dynamic')

class ContactClient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'contacts_clients'
    business_mail = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key=True)
    ddi = db.Column(db.Integer)
    ddd = db.Column(db.Integer)
    phone = db.Column(db.Integer)
    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clients.code'), nullable=False)
```

code of the test:

```
import unittest
from app import create_app, db
from app.models.clients import Client, ContactClient, FiscalClient

class ClientModelTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_client(self):
        cl1 = Client(code=1, name_fantasy='empresa_test')
        db.session.add(cl1)
        db.session.commit()

    def test_contact(self):
        cl1 = ContactClient(business_mail='empresa_test@example.com', ddi=55, 
                             ddd=11, phone=12345678, client_id=1)
        db.session.add(cl1)
        db.session.commit()
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me in this test case

Answer (score 0):

[`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp)/[`tearDown`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) are executed before/after each test method. In your case it creates and drops all tables for each test method, so there are no side-effects left: test method `test_contact` won't see `Client` object created by `test_client` method.

If you would like to work with side-effects, then you'll need to use [`setUpClass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass)/[`tearDownClass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass) instead of `setUp`/`tearDown`.

Without side-effects, you will need to create all related objects inside each test method, like this:

```
class ClientModelTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        ...

    def test_contact(self):
        client = Client(code=1, name_fantasy='empresa_test')
        db.session.add(client)
        contact = ContactClient(business_mail='empresa_test@example.com', ddi=55, 
                                ddd=11, phone=12345678, client=client)
        db.session.add(contact)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: it worked perfectly well.

Changing the setUp and tearDown also made it much easier to make testing faster.

Thank you very much